# Convert KVM virtual machine to LXC container

Tags: debian, linux-kvm

I have 2 virtual machines (with Debian, using KVM) with virtual hard drives:

- /srv/kvm/ssh.img
- /srv/kvm/www.img

Both have 3 partitions (/, /home, swap).

I want to convert them in a RootFS usable with LXC (in order to use LXC instead of KVM).

The only solution I have for the moment is:

- create a new RootFS
- copy /home partition into it
- reproduce the same configuration into it

But is there an automated way to do it

Comment: I doubt it since LXC is highly dependable on the type of kernel used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can give this a shot [Booting an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine in an LXC container](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/03/04/booting-an-ubuntu-12-04-virtual-machine-in-an-lxc-container/) . At least LXC on Ubuntu provides various distro templates, I believe you can boot different Linux distro from the host.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [lxc-convert here](https://wiki.deimos.fr/LXC_:_Install_and_configure_the_Linux_Containers#Convert.2FMigrate_a_VM.2FHost_to_a_LXC_container).

I've done it several time, it works well.